# How do I add an external properties file to a spring-boot project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I currently have the following...

```
(in I:\Code\my-project)
props
  test.properties
target
  test.jar
```

When I run `java -jar target\test.jar` I get...

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

So I try `java -jar target\test.jar --spring.config.name=test --spring.config.location=file:I:\Code\my-project\props` but I get the same error.

How do I include an external properties file on the classpath of a spring-boot project?

The config is simple and looks like this...

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:test.properties")
public class TestConfiguration {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it...

```
java -cp target\test.jar;props -Dloader.main=com.me.Main org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```